# WebAPI Get method with Paging, Sorting and Filtering

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, get, parameter-passing

I am creating a WebAPI where a get method needs to accept, among others, parameters for Paging, Sorting and Filtering.
Since sorting and filtering can be lists of key - value pairs and filtering has operators as well (gt, lt, equals, contains...), and we know that sending objects in the body is not recommended for get methods, how is this scenario handled for APIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply pass them as `Query String`.
It's best practice for behaviours like paging, sorting and filtering because it can be bookmarked by users and reused.

You can see your answer in many famous websites, for example in SO look at the filter param below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=Newest&filters=NoAnswers,NoAcceptedAnswer,Bounty

---

@AdrianoRepetti has a lot of helpfull complementarities in comments that I added to answer with permission:

There are a few different approaches:

For example for Sorting:

http://www.example.com/api/orders?sort=field1,field2

or http://www.example.com/api/order?sort=field1&sort=field2

Now let's make it better: you will also need the sort order, it could be nicely expressed as:

http://www.example.com/api/orders?sort=created_at+asc,delivered_at+desc.

Filters could possibly more more complicate. A simple scenario:

http://www.example.com/api/order?filter=status%3dpending (note **%3d** to escape **=**, the API will see `status=pending` for the filter parameter). Do you need more ANDed filters? just concatenate or repeat them (like for sorting). Instead of %3d you could have other characters if you support other operators. If things get more complicate then you'll need your own mini language to express your filters (remember to encode the URI components client side!!!)

Sooner or later you will need to make your query more complicate and then too long to fit in the query string (for example when you will need an `IN` operator). It's perfectly acceptable (and widely used) to have `POST` instead of `GET` for such queries (see `OpenData`, for example). You could come up with some more complicate scheme for your filters but a simple `JSON` object (or hem hem `GraphQL`) is often a better and easier choice

Comment: I understand your point but what about when filtering and sorting have multiple values, not just one? Filter by 1, 2, 3, order by 1, 2

Comment: To elaborate a little bit: there are a few different approaches. Sorting first: `example.com/api/orders?sort=field1,field2` or `example.com/api/order?sort=field1&sort=field2`.

Comment: Filters could possibly more more complicate. A simple scenario: `example.com/api/order?filter=status%3dpending` (note %3d to escape `=`, the API will _see_ `"status=pending"` for the `filter` parameter). Do you need more ANDed filters? just concatenate or repeat them (like for sorting). Instead of `%3d` you could have other characters if you support other operators. If things get more complicate then you'll need your own mini language to express your filters (remember to encode the URI components client side!!!).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Very helpfull details, meybe good if posted as new answer or added as update to this answer

Comment: Now let's make it better: you will also need the sort order, it could be nicely expressed as `example.com/api/orders?sort=created_at asc,delivered_at desc`. Sooner or later you will need to make your query more complicate and then too long to fit in the query string (for example when you will need an `IN` operator). It's perfectly acceptable (and widely used) to have `POST` instead of `GET` for such queries (see opendata, for example). You could come up with some more complicate scheme for your filters but a simple JSON object (or hem hem GraphQL) is often a better and easier choice.

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimpour feel free to update this answer if you think it could be useful for future readers

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I feel that a Post is a lot less work. No parsing of the query string needed. Object already exists so just send it over.Thank you very much for elaborate answer.

Comment: @elector yes, especially if the filter is a complex expression it's much easier to have it "ready to use" than to parse a string. Not UX friendly for your API to be used with `curl` but a typical web client won't see much of a difference.